# How to use R to extract a context between two characters while still keeping these two signals?

Tags: r, regex, replace, extract, between

For example:

```
a <- 'i am a <> student <>'
```

I want to extract or replace the context between > and < while still keeping > and <. So, if it is extracting, then the result is:

```
 student
```

If it is replacing it with --, then result is:

```
'i am a <>--<>'
```

I have already tried str_extract and str_replace_all, but they did not work.

Comment: Hi  Feng Chen, I wonder if I could make a small request? When asking questions, we would rather they were written in a technical and neutral style. Chatty material that begs, pleads and implores readers for an answer may be thought of as somewhat coercive, and is not really appropriate for the volunteer audience. Please keep it succinct. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned `str_extract` and `str_replace`, we can use them with positive lookahead and lookbehind regex in the following way.

```
library(stringr)

str_extract(a, "(?<=<> ).*(?= <>)")
#[1] "student"
```

And using the same regex in `str_replace`

```
str_replace(a, "(?<=<>).*(?=<>)", "--")
#[1] "i am a <>--<>"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!, May I ask one more case: what is the string is 'i <1> am <> a <1> student <>'? I want the result is: 'am student'. i.e., find all the text between <1> and <>?

Comment: text between`<1>` and `<>` is `am <> a <1> student`. For that you can do `str_extract(a, "(?<=<1> ).*(?= <>)")`

Comment: I mean there are 2 groups of <1> and <>: <1> am <>, and <1> student <>. So, the reslut is: am student.

Comment: @FengChen ahh..I see. In that case, i'll take a different approach. Try `paste0(qdapRegex::ex_between(a, "<1>", "<>")[[1]], collapse = " ")`

Answer (score 1):

Using `sub` to replace only a single occurrence:

```
a <- 'i am a <> student <>'
out <- sub(">[^<]+<", ">--<", a)
out

[1] "i am a <>--<>"
```

To extract just a single context:

```
sub("^.*>\\s*([^<]+?)\\s*<.*$", "\\1", a)

[1] "student"
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you also tell me how to extract just the context between two characters?